# Need to groupby on one column add get the count of other column in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, group-by, hive, hiveql

Here is the sample data I have:

[image: input]

in the above table, we can see a1,a2,a3 and a4 all having src1. I need only a3 and a4 as the result, as they are the only rows with only src1 embedded to it. a1 and a2 have other src2,... etc.

I need a hive query to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate by `col1`, and use a `having` clause to filter on `col1`s whose only value for `col2` is `'src1'`.

```
select col1
from mytable
group by col1
having min(col2) = max(col2) and min(col2) = 'src1'
```